# Linear Algebra, trying to understand the procedure.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone tell me how to solve this type of exercise?

Problem 1.17

Given $z  \neq 1$, prove that $\frac {1 + z}{1-z}$ is purely imaginary if and only if $|z| = 1$

Comment: Hint:  $\frac 1{1-z}=(1-\overline z\,)|1-z|^2$.

Answer (score 1):

A number $w\in\mathbb{C}$ is purely imaginary if and only if $\bar{w}=-w$. So try and compute
$$
\frac{1+z}{1-z}+\frac{1+\bar{z}}{1-\bar{z}}=
\frac{1-\bar{z}+z-z\bar{z}+1+\bar{z}-z-z\bar{z}}{(1-z)(1-\bar{z})}=
\frac{2(1-z\bar{z})}{(1-z)(1-\bar{z})}
$$
When is this $0$?

Answer (score 0):

Reverse side:
Assume $\frac{1+z}{1-z}$ is purely imaginary. That is, for a *real* $\lambda$,
$$\frac{1+z}{1-z} = \lambda i \implies z = \frac{\lambda i - 1}{\lambda i + 1} \implies |z| = \frac{\sqrt{1 + \lambda^2}}{\sqrt{1 + \lambda^2}} = 1$$

Front side:
$$\frac{1+z}{1-z} = \frac{(1+z)(1-\overline z)}{(1-z)(1-\overline z)} = \frac{z - \overline z}{2-z-\overline z} = \frac{2iy}{2-2x} = \mu i$$ for a *real* $\mu$.